# Check which printer in net use lpt1 is connected

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, .net-core

I have a question, in this program I mapped a label network printer, so I would like to know which printer I am connected to, this is my function. Is there any function I could use to know where the printer I am connected?

Ex "You are connected to printer "DESKTOP01"

```
public void impressora(string computador)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = $@"/c net use lpt1: /delete & net use lpt1: \\{computador}\zpl";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process. Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I find how to get the response...

```
    public void checkimpressora()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"/c net use lpt1:";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.Start();
        string q = "";
        q += process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string m = q.Replace("Local name        LPT1", " ").Replace("Resource type     Print", " ").Replace("Status            OK", " ").Replace("# Opens           0", "").Replace("# Connections     1", " ").Replace("The command completed successfully.", " ").Replace(@"Remote name       \\", " ").Replace(@"\zpl", " ").Replace(" ", "").Replace("\r\n", "");
        if (m != "")
        {
            if (m == "BRMAOPR094")
            {
                resetallbuttons();
                changecolor(pcm);
            }
        } 
    }
```